# add text field dynamically in to a html table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxField = 10;
  var addButton = $('.add_button');
  var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper');
  var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="Tape_Code[]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field">delete</a></div>';
  var x = 1;
  $(addButton).click(function() {
    if (x < maxField) {
      x++;
      $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML);
    }
  });
  $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  });
});
```

```html
<?php
  include_once 'dpconnect.php';
  $que=mysqli_query($MySQLiconn,"select Backup_Name from admin_backup_list ");
  if(isset($_POST['confirm'])) {
     $Date=date('d/m/y');
     $Backup_Name=$_POST['Backup_Name'];
     $Tape_Code = $_POST['Tape_Code'];
     $Operator_Approval = $_POST['Operator_Approval'];
     $Operator_Remark = $_POST['Operator_Remark'];

     $abc=mysqli_query($MySQLiconn,"insert into backup_details(Date, Backup_Name, Tape_Code,Operator_Approval,Operator_Remark)values('$Backup_Name','$Tape_Code','$Operator_Approval','$Operator_Remark')");
   }

?>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php $Date=date( 'd/m/y'); ?>


<form name="form2" action="" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td width="103">Date</td>
      <td width="94">Backup_Name</td>
      <td width="94">No Of Tapes</td>
      <td width="53">Tape Code</td>
      <td width="71">Operator Approval</td>
      <td width="144">Operator Remark</td>

    </tr>
    <?php if ($que->num_rows > 0) { while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($que)) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <?php echo $Date; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $row[ 'Backup_Name']; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="No_Of_Backup">
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="field_wrapper">
          <input type="text" name="Tape_Code" value="" /><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">add</a>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Operator_Approval">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Operator_Remark">
      </td>
      <td colspan="8">
        <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Confirm">
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } } ?>

  </table>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm doing this code in php. I need a help to add text fields dynamically in to the table's particular column. I have done the code using JavaScript also. But the problem is when I add field in one row, all rows are updating with extra fields. I need a help. How can I insert those data to MySQL?

Comment: You want more than one tap code for single row right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are using the class selector to select the elements. Class selector returns array like object of all the elements having that class.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

you can find out which element was clicked if you change your code similar to below one.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field" onclick="addButton(event);">add</a>
```

and in the script

```
      function addButton(ev) {
        var clickedElement = console.log(ev.target);
      }
```

Now you have the element which was clicked by user and you can find the parent td/tr and append html for textbox.

Answer (score 0):

In `$Tape_Code = $_POST['Tape_Code'];` You will get array of text input you have to insert it in database in form that you want.

```
$Tape_Code = $_POST['Tape_Code']
foreach($Tape_Code as $code){
   echo $code;
}
```